# Colorful Hypnotic Swirl in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

How could one create such a hypnotic swirl in animation-nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The *Distribute Matrix* node have a built-in spiral type:

[image: Node Tree]